# Printer stopped working after uninstalling image-magic

Tags: 16.04, printing, cups-lpd

As I was unable to remove imagemagick via the software center I uninstalled imagemagick via the command line with `sudo apt remove imagemagick` and `sudo apt autoremove` After this My printer stopped working and when I checked under printers it showed in the status line `/usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd does not exist!` How can I fix this and get it working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing imagemagick had the unintended consequence of taking cups out with it.

I resolved the problem with the following commands:

`sudo apt install imagemagick` followed by

`sudo apt install cups`

Reboot and all is well.